# How do I preview my report in this version of SSRS(not sure which version it is)?

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008

I need help figuring out how to navigate SSRS. I've been using SSRS using remote desktop , but when i switched to local machine and installed BIDS on Visual Studio, I see that SSRS looks quite different... here's a screenshot( [click her eto see full-screen view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z0cD6.png) ) :

[image]

Is this SSRS-2008? Or the newest version -

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That looks like the version of BIDS installed by SQL Server 2012. Use the Menu Help / About to be sure.

Comment: +1 Definitely BIDS 2012 (with Visual Studio 2010.) 2008R2 uses Visual Studio 2008.

Comment: BIDS is a common acronym for "SQL Server Business Intelligence Development Studio", which is what the Start Menu shortcut for Visual Studio is named when you install the SQL Server Management Tools.  Under the covers both BIDS and Visual Studio point to the same executable e.g. devenv.exe.

Comment: Would you know how to install the older versiion of BIDS - that is , version 10.50.2796.0  -  thanks?

Comment: Use SQL Server 2008R2 installation media to install that version of BIDS.